# Retrieve attribute value from one xml and use it as a value for another attribute in other xml file

Tags: xml

Say I have File1.xml and File2.xml

File1.xml has the following :

```
<tag1 attribute1 = "value1" attribute2 = "value2">tagvalue</tag1>
```

I want the following in  File2 to have the below :

```
<tag2 attribute1 = "value of the attribute1 of the tag1 in file1" />
```

Please let me know if I am not clear with my question.

Comment: What is tool you want to use? It is possible by XSLT, C#, VB.NET and by many other ways.

Comment: A solution in XSLT will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let, there is file1.xml that contains

```
<tags>
    <tag1 attribute1 = "value1" attribute2 = "value2">tagvalue</tag1>
    <tag2 attribute1 = "value21" attribute2 = "value22">tagvalue</tag2>
    <tag3 attribute1 = "value31" attribute2 = "value22">tagvalue</tag3>
</tags>
```

Then you could use following transformation:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <tags>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" />
    </tags>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*/*">
      <xsl:element name="tag2">
        <xsl:attribute name="attribute1">
            <xsl:text>value of the attribute1 of the attribute1 of </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text> is </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@attribute1"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this piece of script help me fetch the value of an attribute of a tag in file1.xml and use it as a value of an attribute of an element/tag in another xml file?

Comment: @user8107531, you could use [online tool](http://xsltransform.net/) to see transformation result.